# Create dynamic query for Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have two entities:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String firstName;

private String lastName;

@Relationship(type = "IN")
private Department department;

}

@NodeEntity
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

I need have a logic for search firstName, lastName and department id.
I looked at repository approach and can't find solution, because my query is dynamic (there can be 0 or 3 parameters in search query).

What is the best solution for such task? Now I managed to do it with manual query building and Session object like this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("MATCH (user:User)-[:IN]->(department:Department) WHERE ");
 if (departmentId != null) {
        builder.append(String.format("ID(department) = %s", departmentId));
        builder.append(" AND ");
 }
 ...
List<User> userList  =  Lists.newArrayList(session.query(User.class,builder.toString(), Collections.emptyMap()));
```

But it looks ugly and I wanna find better solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With the [`CASE expressions`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/expressions/#query-syntax-case) you can take all the logic inside the cypher-query:

```
MATCH (U:User)-[:IN]->(D:Department) WHERE
  CASE WHEN NOT $firstName IS NULL 
    THEN U.firstName = $search.firstName 
    ELSE TRUE 
  END AND
  CASE WHEN NOT $lasrName IS NULL 
    THEN U.lastName = $lastName 
    ELSE TRUE 
  END AND
  CASE WHEN NOT $departmentId IS NULL 
    THEN ID(D) = $departmentId 
    ELSE TRUE 
  END    
RETURN *
```